# kivy images not displaying

Tags: python, image, user-interface, kivy

Im new to Kivy. What I am trying to do, is display all the images in a directory and the user can scroll down through them.

I have run into an issue, for one of the folders in the directory all the images are displayed as white rectangles, I cannot understand why. The images in another directory are displayed fine... here is the source code:

```
    class vAll(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (vAll, self).__init__(**kwargs)

 #       os.chdir("/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages")
        popup = Popup(title='View all', size_hint=(1,1), auto_dismiss=False)
        ims = []

        directory_list = list()
        for root, dirs, files in  os.walk("/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages", topdown=False):
            for name in dirs:
                directory_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))

        print directory_list
        #this layout is the child widget for the main popup
        layout1 = StackLayout(orientation='lr-bt')

            #this button is a child of layout1
        closebutton = Button(text='back', size_hint=(0.8,0.05))
        closebutton.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        sz = 1
        for d in directory_list:
            os.chdir(d)
            for fn in glob.glob("*.png"):
        #return Image(source=fn,size=(10,10))
                ims.append(fn)
            for im in ims:
                print im
                i = AsyncImage(source=im)
                sz = sz + 1
        #another child of layout1 and this is the scrollview which will have a custom draggable scrollbar
        scrlv = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.9,0.95))
        layout2 = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint_y= sz/10+4)
        layout2.bind(minimum_height=layout2.setter('height'))

        for im in ims:
          i = Image(source=im)
          layout2.add_widget(i)
        scrlv.add_widget(layout2)
        layout1.add_widget(closebutton)
        layout1.add_widget(scrlv)
        self.add_widget(layout1)


        def scroll_change(self, scrlv, instance, value):
            scrlv.scroll_y = value


    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'home'
```

Comment: sorry for the horrible code, im just playing around trying to get this to work

Comment: White rectangles usually imply that either path to image is invalid or the format is not supported.